# How to use adaptive launcher icons with a progressive web app

Tags: android, icons, progressive-web-apps, adaptive-icon

The new Android 8.0 standard for [adaptive launcher icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) leaves my PWA's icon in a white box or circle, depending on what icon shape is set on a user's device. I would like to include an adaptive icon with my PWA but am not finding any documentation around this at all.

Is there a way to include meta and different icons for different shapes or a way to include the necessary layers for an adaptive icon?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: No. However, I haven't looked into it again since posting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard to support what you need. [Icon Masks in PWA](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#icon-masks).

Basically, you will have to add `"purpose": "maskable"` to your icon definition in the manifest.

It's still a work-in-progress ([Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977173)). Firefox for android already supports it.

Comment: Curiously, this works for me on Chrome, but [not on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60485013/5085211).