# Adding to home screen on Android Firefox does not mask icon

Tags: android, firefox, progressive-web-apps, firefox-android

The [Google documentation](https://web.dev/add-manifest/) on web app manifests specifies that in order to make web app icons mask properly, an icon should be marked as `"purpose": "any maskable"`. This works well on Chrome on Android but the mask fails to mask as expected when using "Add to home screen" in Firefox Android (Android 10, Firefox Mobile 68.5.0).

[image]

In my manifest, I'm providing icons of sizes 192x192 and 512x512; Firefox does indeed take one of the icons from the manifest; it's just not performing the desired masking:

```
{
  "background_color": "#00bf00",
  "description": "...",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
     {
      "src": "plug-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "plug-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    }
  ],
  "name": "...",
  "short_name": "...",
  "start_url": "/"
}
```

If I "install" the app, rather than just "add it to home screen" through the hamburger menu (and this time with a different icon that furthermore uses transparency), the situation is slightly better, but the Firefox version still looks rather poor (being pixelated and using a different convention for transparency than Chrome), cf. the screenshot below (Chrome "installed web app" on the left, Firefox on the right):

[image]

So my question simply becomes:

> Is there any way to coerce Android Firefox into producing a result something that looks like what Chrome (and indeed, typical Android apps) produces?

Answer (score 1):

The current Firefox release version doesn't support maskable icons. It works in Firefox Beta and will work once that version makes its way to the stable channel.

Comment: Any update on this as of April 2022?

Comment: This should work on stable last I checked

Comment: It still doesn't work on last version of Firefox nor on beta from what I can see. Works perfectly on Chrome.