# Does the current version of Firefox Android support maskable-icons?

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox

Is the current version of Firefox Android supposed to support maskable-icons? Apparently, according to a comment on this thread: [Adding to home screen on Android Firefox does not mask icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485013/adding-to-home-screen-on-android-firefox-does-not-mask-icon/62940701) it is supposed to work, but I don't seem to be able to make it work on my end.

It works perfectly with Google Chrome.

Here is the manifest.json, extremely simple :

```
{
"icons": [
    {
        "src": "/maskable-152x152.png",
        "sizes": "152x152",
        "type": "image/png",
        "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png",
        "sizes": "152x152",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png",
        "sizes": "120x120",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png",
        "sizes": "114x114",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png",
        "sizes": "76x76",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png",
        "sizes": "60x60",
        "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
        "src": "/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png",
        "sizes": "57x57",
        "type": "image/png"
    }
]
```

}

Any ideas?